# Android Studio doesnt build after update

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just updated Android Studio to build 130.729444, and my project (which built correctly before the update) has stopped to work, and Android Studio shows me the following error:

```
Internal error: (java.lang.AssertionError) Unexpected node Android Packaging; nodes=[Module 'MyApplication' production, Module 'MyApplicationProject' production, Module 'MyApplication' tests, Module 'MyApplicationProject' tests, Resources for 'MyApplication' production, Resources for 'MyApplicationProject' production, Resources for 'MyApplication' tests, Resources for 'MyApplicationProject' tests, Artifact 'MyApplication', Android Gradle Build Target]
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected node Android Packaging; nodes=[Module 'MyApplication' production, Module 'MyApplicationProject' production, Module 'MyApplication' tests, Module 'MyApplicationProject' tests, Resources for 'MyApplication' production, Resources for 'MyApplicationProject' production, Resources for 'MyApplication' tests, Resources for 'MyApplicationProject' tests, Artifact 'MyApplication', Android Gradle Build Target]
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.buildOuts(GraphGenerator.java:55)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.<init>(GraphGenerator.java:36)
    at com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.create(GraphGenerator.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildTargetIndexImpl.initializeChunks(BuildTargetIndexImpl.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildTargetIndexImpl.getSortedTargetChunks(BuildTargetIndexImpl.java:105)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:578)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:341)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:223)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:130)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Anyone know how to solve this? I've thinking about returning to old version, but I want to know if it's my problem or I'm not the only one.

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried to shut down the plugins oe by one to find where com.intellij.util.graph.GraphGenerator.buildOuts is used. It turns out that when I turn on the combination of JUnit and Android plugins this error occurs. Not much of an answer but a possible step in the right direction.

Comment: I think you'd better update you Android Studio First. Your version 130.729444, which is 0.1.9 according to google. However, the lastest is 0.2.4 (130.777423). There are a lot of fix between the two versions and I suggest you to upgrade and then try again.

Comment: Looks like the issue may be caused by trying to use Artifacts in Android Studio. I thought it would just be a quicker way to build my app for testing on a friends phone. I removed the artifact i had made and my app buld now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently filed a [bug report to Google](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57368). According to the thread in the [Android developer tools forum](https://plus.google.com/110202031007784040928/posts/gVytVimjaAb) this is an issue they can´t directly explain. I think this is as good as an answer we can get untill this bug is adressed by the developers.

Answer (score 8):

Get same issue with IntelliJ 14 when try to add artifact. Removing *.idea/artifact* folder solves issue.